# JFreeChart not showing XYPlot series axis labels

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using a `XYPlot` in a `TimeSeriesChart`. I have a `dateAxis` and `valueAxis` (log) for displaying few time series. My issue is I need the end prices of the series on the right-side-axis next to the end of the series. I am not interested for the axis labels, since the same can be approximated on the left. Something similar to the red circle in the attached chart.

What is the best way to do this? I modified a copy of `PriceVolumeDemo1.java` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76644701/1). I tried a few variations, but it's not working. This shows the labels similar to what I want:

[image]

Comment: What's not working? Using `mapDatasetToRangeAxis()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjfreechart%5D+mapDatasetToRangeAxis), is the usual approach. Please [edit] your question to include your own [mre] that shows your revised approach focusing on your use-case with minimal data.

Comment: Hi trashgod, Thanks for taking interest.